# Suitable patterns for stating general availability

Tags: design-patterns

Does anyone have any suggestions of how best to allow a user state their **general** availability?

Scenario: managing appointments

Further info: The user in their profile has the ability to set the times they are generally available. See screen shot for an idea.

What I was looking for was either alternative patterns for this or other suggestions.
[image]

Comment: Are these the only possible time ranges? Are users able to create fine grain set of times?

Comment: Yes and no :) The idea isn't a fully blown booking system. The actual booking will happen outside the system. So this is to purely give an indication on when the user is usually available.

Comment: Is it only the times or they can also be available all days at a certain time, then you need to think about that dimension too.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider flipping the X and Y axis, so the days of week becomes column header.  This is how most calendars are formatted, so it's good to stick with convention.

I would also put duration, since the night shift is two times longer than other shifts.

Nice-to-have:

Some kind of validation that alerts users of potentially invalid selections. (e.g. selecting more than 16 hours availability per day)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1aVoH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: What if they want to make themselves available for the entire 24 hour period?